# Does reading a volatile reference to an object guarantee atomic reads of the latest values of its properties?

Tags: java, concurrency

Assuming that all properties are not `long` or `double`, does reading a `volatile` reference to an object guarantee atomic reads of the latest values of its properties?

Here's a concrete example.

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;

    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Baz {
    private volatile Foo foo;
}
```

Thread A may write to `Foo`'s `Bar` property any time. Thread B can only read `Foo`'s `Bar` property. If thread B accesses the `Bar` property through `Baz`, will it read the latest value of `Bar`?

Comment: Immutability will make your life much easier here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short no. The `volatile` keyword only applies to the `foo` reference, not to the fields of the underlying object.

So you would need to mark `bar` as `volatile` too to achieve the result your describe.

Answer (score 4):

Good question but the answer is *no*.  The read of a volatile variable synchronizes with the last time it was written to.

So, a non-null `baz` ensures at least the first value of `foo.bar` but not any successive write.  That is of course if `foo.bar` is written to prior to the write of `baz`